# How do I close a slide-in nav bar on resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a responsive navigation bar that collapses into a burger menu at a certain width. When I click on the menu, the links slide in from the right. However, when I resize the browser to a width that restores the standard nav bar, then I resize the browser back to the width where the nav collapses into a burger menu, the nav links are still there instead of just the menu. I need it so that even if I don't close the menu manually, it will close when I resize back to a desktop width, and if I return to a mobile width, I will have to open the menu again to see the links. This is only an issue if I open the menu, don't close it, resize, and then return. If I close it, resize, and then return, of course the nav links aren't there.

HTML

```
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="file.html" class="nav-link" id="active">Text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="file.html" class="nav-link">Text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="file.html" class="nav-link">Text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="file.html" class="nav-link">Text</a></li>
                    <li><a href="file.html" class="nav-link">Text</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="menu" onclick="closeFunction(this);">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
```

CSS (scroll to see all)

```
.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: .2s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        right: 0px;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: var(--media-nav-links-background-color);
        z-index: 1;
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    .menu {
        display: block;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: .4s;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

    menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    });
}

navSlide();
```

I'm guessing there's something I should add to the JS.

NEW PROBLEM

@54ka's answer worked. However, now I have the same problem but with the burger menu animation. The menu bars turn into an X when clicked and then back when clicked again. If I click the menu, the X appears, I resize then return, the X is still there, not the menu, and then of course the sync with the nav links sliding in is thrown off b/c again @54ka's answer solved the nav slide. I tried just applying the same solution to my JS that controls the X transition and it worked but then undid the solution to the original problem, the nav links now don't close on resize even though that was just fixed. Very odd.

Here's the info about the close function:

HTML

```
            <div class="menu" onclick="closeFunction(this);">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: .2s;
}

.menu:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: var(--menu-div-background-color);
    transition: .4s;
}

.close .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4px, 6px);
}

.close .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.close .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-4px, -6px);
}
```

JavaScript

```
function closeFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle('close');
}
```

JS that I tried

```
function closeFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle('close');

    window.onresize = function () {
        var w = window.outerWidth;
        if (w > 1200) {
            x.classList.remove('close');
        }
    };
}
```

Again, this JS I tried solved it, but then it "undid" so to speak the JS that solved my original problem:

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

    menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    });

    window.onresize = function () {
        var w = window.outerWidth;
        if (w > 1200) {
            nav.classList.remove('nav-active');
        }
    };
}
```

Any suggestions? Perhaps there's a way to merge these JavaScripts so everything happens together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add code window listener for the screen size and remove `nav-active` if it is above the specified value

```
window.onresize = function () {
    var w = window.outerWidth;
    if (w > 1200) {
        nav.classList.remove('nav-active');
    }
};
```

**Example:**

*In the example, I changed the maximum resolution to 600px.
And I removed `onclick ="closeFunction (this);` which I don't know what it does and because it is not defined in the code it returns an error*

```js
const navSlide = () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

    menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    });

    window.onresize = function () {
        var w = window.outerWidth;
        if (w > 600) {
            nav.classList.remove('nav-active');
        }
    };

}

navSlide();
```

```css
.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: .2s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        /* right: 0px; */
        align-items: center;
        background-color: var(--media-nav-links-background-color);
        z-index: 1;
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    .menu {
        display: block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #000;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="file.html" class="nav-link" id="active">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="file.html" class="nav-link">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="file.html" class="nav-link">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="file.html" class="nav-link">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="file.html" class="nav-link">Text</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="menu" onclick="">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Answer to the new task:**

```
function closeFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle('close');
}

const navSlide = () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

    menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    });

    window.onresize = function () {
        var w = window.outerWidth;
        if (w > 1200) {
            nav.classList.remove('nav-active');
            document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0].setAttribute('class', 'menu');
        }
    };
}

navSlide();
```

Comment: So this worked, but about that closeFunction(this), that animates the menu bars to turn into an X when clicked and then return when clicked again. So, when I open the menu, resize, then return, the nav links aren't there, so that worked, but the X is still there, not the menu. New problem. I have edited the OP so you can see.